# How do I remove the line "Connection established." from the PHP to SQL Server connection script?

Tags: php, connection, database-connection

I've made a connection between PHP and SQL Server using XAMPP with the code below:

**koneksi.php**

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.6"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"goldmart", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Close the connection.
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>
```

This is the result when I run the code above:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcZDZ.jpg)

Then I display the data with the following code, but the message "Connection established." appear.

**tes.php**

```
<?php 
include "koneksi.php";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.mJenis";
$call=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($call === false){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($call, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['kode'].", ".$row['Nama']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $call);
?>
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxs3i.jpg)

The question is: how do I remove the message "Connection established."??

I've been browsing and can't find how to solve this problem. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to call `$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);`  again, it already exists in your `koneksi.php` file, you can use `$conn` directly, but should use `require_once __DIR__ . "/koneksi.php";` instead of `include`. To avoid obscure issues with redirecting etc, you should not use the php closing tag `?>` unless switching to a different non-php content-type.

Comment: I just tried it, but the following error message appears: https://prnt.sc/kI9w2SuoB2AG

Comment: Remove the line `sqlsrv_close( $conn );` in the include file, since there's no real reason to close the connection and reconnect again afterwards when you only include the file to enable a connection to the database. If you intend to include it on every page, create a wrapper function to initiate the connection only when needed like so: https://3v4l.org/KSlVl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Only print the error in case the connection is not established:

```
if( !$conn ) {
  echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

b) Also use `sqlsrv_close( $conn );` in your other code file, not in the connection code file.

c) remove `$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);` from your other file as you already have the connection code included.

So the code needs to be like this:

Connection file (`koneksi.php`):

```
<?php
    $serverName = "192.168.0.6";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"goldmart", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( !$conn ) {
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

Another file:

```
<?php 
    include "koneksi.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.mJenis";
    $call = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if($call === false){
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($call, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['kode'].", ".$row['Nama']."<br />";
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $call);
    // Close the connection.
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks; it works. Your explanation is very detailed, which I can understand.

Answer (score -1):

I’m guessing this code is in the `koneski.php` file:

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.6"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"goldmart", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Close the connection.
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>
```

When you `include` the file, everything inside the `koneski.php` file is included. So, simply remove this line of code:

```
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Change it to:

```
// If the connection could not be established, die and print the errors
if(!$conn ) {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Also, change the SQL close to being in the main file, rather than the `koneski.php` file.

`koneski.php`:

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.6"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"goldmart", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(!$conn ) {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

`Tes.php`:

```
<?php 
include "koneksi.php";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.mJenis";
$call=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($call === false){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($call, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['kode'].", ".$row['Nama']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $call);
// Close the connection.
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
?>
```

Comment: I just changed koneksi.php file and remove `$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo); `, but when I run the test.php file, the following error message appears: https://prnt.sc/kI9w2SuoB2AG

Comment: I noticed that you ended the SQL connection in the `koneski.php` file. All you need to do is remove the 'sqlsrv_close($con);`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: There must be no echo and no die()